# Cannot find main repository, you have to tag one as main!

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu, installing-fonts

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I tried to install [Minon Prop](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) Latex package, which is a font, (for texlive) using this command: `tlmgr install minionpro`

But I got this error message:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
tlmgr: Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
Use of uninitialized value $r in split at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 3882.
tlmgr: Cannot find main repository, you have to tag one as main!
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure that you don't need super user privileges?
What about `sudo tlmgr install minionpro`?

Comment: I run `tlmgr init-usertree` previously to that. But just to be sure, I run the above command again after `sudo` but I got exactly the same error @AlessandroCuttin

Comment: Are you using the LaTeX distribution provided by Ubuntu?
Debian (except unstable) and Ubuntu are not up to date with TeX Live.  I would recommend installing TeX Live directly from [TUG](http://tug.org/texlive/) instead of using the Debian packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the TeX Live distribution as shipped by Debian, that means `tlmgr` only works in user-mode. After you have set up the user tree as you have described, you should be able to first set the remote repository with `tlmgr option repository URL`, and then install the required packages with `tlmgr install PKG`.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that xzdec in not installed. Try using:

```
sudo apt-get install xzdec
```

As this resolved the issue for me.